# Problem auto-assigning sequential value for new items

Tags: c#, linq, service, ria, iqueryable

A feature in an application I'm debugging allows users to create reviews for products. The input form has a ReviewId field that is autopopulated based on the number of existing reviews - it increases sequentially by '1.' For existing products, this works fine.

For a new product, there are no previous reviews, so when the user tries to create one, the application throws a domain services exception. I know this is because there is some code looking for the last review Id but since it's a new product, there isn't one and that causes the error. I just can't figure out the code needed to fix it (PHP programmer working in C#/Silverlight). I don't have access to the modifying the database, so I'm trying to do this programmatically.

Here is what I have:

**AddReviewChildWindow.cs –**

> public void GetNewReviewNumber()
>   
> {
>
> > ReviewsDomainContext review = new ReviewsDomainContext();
> > InvokeOperation count = review.GetLastReviewNumber(ProductId);
> > count.Completed += new System.EventHandler(GetNewReviewNumberCompleted);
>
> }

**And the DomainServices.cs –**

> [Description( "Returns the id number of the last review associated with a product." )]
> [Invoke]
>
> public System.Int32 GetLastReviewNumber( Nullable productId )
> {
>
> > int retVal = 0; 
> >
> > //Get the list of reviews for product.
> > IQueryable reviews = GetProductReviews( productId );
> >
> > //Get the last one.
> > Review review = reviews.Last();
> >
> > //Assign new one.
> > retVal = review.ReviewNumber;
> > retVal++;//add one to it.
> > return retVal;
>
> }

This should be an easy one for someone who knows C#, I would think - but I just can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: A mite off-topic, but that ReviewId form field for new reviews isn't a sound design. Imagine User A opens the form and gets ReviewId=2, then User B opens the form and also gets ReviewId=2, then they both submit... You should generate the ID immediately before inserting the review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this should work:

```
public Int32 GetLastReviewNumber( Nullable productId )
{   
    int retVal = 0;

    //Get the list of reviews for product.
    IQueryable<Review> reviews = GetProductReviews( productId );

    //Get the last one.
    if(reviews.Count() != 0)
    {
        Review review = reviews.Last();

        //Assign new one.
        retVal = review.ReviewNumber;
    }
    retVal++;//add one to it.

    return retVal;    
}
```

Comment: That did it. I figured it was something simple. Thanks!!